# Configure Drools execution on knowledgebase objects

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

suppose I have added some objects

> {O1,O2,O3}

and rules

> {R1,R2,R3}

in my knowledgebase

when I fire all rules the execution order goes like this:

```
R1 <on> O1
R1 <on> O2
R1 <on> O3

R2 <on> O1
R2 <on> O2
R2 <on> O3

R3 <on> O1 (add to passed object cache)
R3 <on> O2 (add to passed object cache)
R3 <on> O3 (add to passed object cache)
```

This means I can't put the passed objects in a cache until the last loop

how to change the execution order to:

```
R1 <on> O1
R2 <on> O1
R3 <on> O1 (add to passed object cache)

R1 <on> O2
R2 <on> O2
R3 <on> O2 (add to passed object cache)

R1 <on> O3
R2 <on> O3
R3 <on> O3 (add to passed object cache)
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert your objects one by one and calling fireAllRules() after each insert?

Comment: Is there anything in the class of your objects Ox (I assume all are of the same class) that determines the order O1 < O2 < O3?

Comment: Please explain why the requested order matters, i.e., how an observer detects that the first order happens, and which negative consequences arise from this. Note that the order of the objects' arrival in the cache is the same, with only a few milliseconds diffrence between the arrival times.

Comment: O1,O2,O3 are selected by rule engine at random, I want to lazy load the passed objects in my cache gradually and not wait for the whole process to end to get the passed objects, as of now my front-end users needs to wait for a long time to see any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Drools Expert User Guide, section 4.3.4.2](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e1898):

> As a general rule, it is a good idea not to count on rules firing in any particular order, and to author the rules without worrying about a "flow".

Even the execution order you've seen is not guaranteed. The example seems to be about imperative style control in the sense of "first do this, then do this, then put the object somewhere." A rule engine is the wrong tool for this job, programming languages like Java are better suited for fine control over loops and such.